Tkinter - CheckboxTreeview with tooltip for each element
I have a Python tool with CheckboxTreeview widget. Some of the content in the treeview is too long to be displayed. I would like to offer a tooltip to the user if this is the case. I already have tooltips in my tool at other places but I'm not able to set the tooltip to individual contents within the CheckboxTreeview. Do you know any way, how this is possible?
Below is a minimum example, where I would like to have the tooltip for the reference ref2. How is this possible?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview

class CreateToolTip(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, text='tooltip text', wraplength=180):
        self.waittime = 400 #miliseconds
        self.bg = '#fdfde3'
        self.wraplength = wraplength   #pixels
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
        self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)
        self.widget.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.leave)
        self.id = None
        self.tw = None

    def enter(self, event=None):
        self.schedule()

    def leave(self, event=None):
        self.unschedule()
        self.hidetip()

    def schedule(self):
        self.unschedule()
        self.id = self.widget.after(self.waittime, self.showtip)

    def unschedule(self):
        id = self.id
        self.id = None
        if id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(id)

    def showtip(self, event=None):
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
        self.tw = tk.Toplevel(self.widget)
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
        tk.Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',background=self.bg,
                 relief='solid', borderwidth=1,wraplength = self.wraplength
                 ).pack(ipadx=10)
        x += self.widget.winfo_rootx()
        y += self.widget.winfo_rooty()
        self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tw
        self.tw= None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()


class App():
    def __init__(self, master):  
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x400')
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tree = CheckboxTreeview(self.master)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set)
        self.tree['columns']=('x', 'y')
        self.tree.column('x', anchor='e', width=40)
        self.tree.column('y', width=40)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='abc', anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('x', text='x', anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('y', text='y', anchor='w')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
        self.master.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
        self.master.frame.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        ref = tk.Label(self.master.frame, text='TEXT', font=tk.font.Font(size=16, weight='bold'))
        ref.grid(row=0, column=0)
        CreateToolTip(ref, text='tooltip')
        
        ref1 = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text='node 1', values=('x1', 'y1'), open=True)
        ref2 = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text='node 2 - this is a very long text where a tooltip should be displayed', values=('x2', 'y2'), open=True)

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.master.mainloop()


You need to remove the dependency on the "insert" bbox and bind the tooltip behavior directly to the tree items. Try this way:
class CreateToolTip(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, text='tooltip text', wraplength=180):
        self.waittime = 400  # milliseconds
        self.hidetime = 2000
        self.wraplength = wraplength   #pixels
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
        self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)
        self.widget.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.leave)
        self.id = None
        self.tw = None
        self.hide_id = None  # new timer for auto-hide

    def enter(self, event=None):
        self.schedule()

    def leave(self, event=None):
        self.unschedule()
        self.schedule_hide()

    def schedule_hide(self):
        if self.hide_id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(self.hide_id)
        self.hide_id = self.widget.after(self.hidetime, self.hidetip)

    def schedule(self):
        self.unschedule()
        self.id = self.widget.after(self.waittime, self.showtip)

    def unschedule(self):
        if self.id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(self.id)
            self.id = None

    def unschedule(self):
        if self.id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(self.id)
            self.id = None
        if self.hide_id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(self.hide_id)
            self.hide_id = None

    def showtip(self, event=None):
        x = self.widget.winfo_rootx() + self.widget.winfo_width()//2
        y = self.widget.winfo_rooty()

        self.hidetip()

        self.tw = tk.Toplevel(self.widget)
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)

        label = tk.Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                      background="#ffffe0", relief='solid', borderwidth=1,
                      wraplength=self.wraplength)
        label.pack()

        self.tw.wm_geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
        self.schedule_hide()

    def hidetip(self):
        if self.tw:
            self.tw.destroy()
            self.tw = None



class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('300x400')
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tree = CheckboxTreeview(self.master)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.master, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set)
        self.tree['columns']=('x', 'y')
        self.tree.column('x', anchor='e', width=40)
        self.tree.column('y', width=40)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='abc', anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('x', text='x', anchor='w')
        self.tree.heading('y', text='y', anchor='w')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')

        self.tree.bind('<Motion>', self.show_tree_tooltip)
        self.current_tooltip = None

        self.master.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=2)
        self.master.frame.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
        ref = tk.Label(self.master.frame, text='TEXT', font=tk.font.Font(size=16, weight='bold'))
        ref.grid(row=0, column=0)
        CreateToolTip(ref, text='This is a ToolTip!!!')

        ref1 = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text='node 1', values=('x1', 'y1'), open=True)
        ref2 = self.tree.insert('', 'end',
                               text='node 2 - this is a very long text where a tooltip should be displayed',
                               values=('x2', 'y2'),
                               open=True)

        self.tooltips = {
            ref1: "Tooltip for node 1",
            ref2: "node 2 - this is a very long text where a tooltip should be displayed"
        }

    def show_tree_tooltip(self, event):
        item = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)

        if not item:
            if self.current_tooltip:
                self.current_tooltip.leave()
            return

        if item in self.tooltips:
            if self.current_tooltip and self.current_tooltip.text != self.tooltips[item]:
                self.current_tooltip.hidetip()
                self.current_tooltip = None

            if not self.current_tooltip:
                self.current_tooltip = CreateToolTip(self.tree, text=self.tooltips[item], wraplength=200)
                self.current_tooltip.showtip()
        else:
            if self.current_tooltip:
                self.current_tooltip.leave()
                self.current_tooltip = None



root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.master.mainloop()

This way, you have separate tooltips for each item. I also added a "timer" to hide the tooltip. You'll need to tweak it further, as my work interval just ended now lol.
Hope this helps! Cheers!
